# Oracle trigger instead of update and ORA-22816 error

Tags: sql, oracle, delphi, view, triggers

I'm working on a Delphi application, using a TcxGrid to manipulate data from a view VM_TEST and a INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger on a Oracle DB to update it.

This is the view's code:

```
create or replace view VM_TEST 
AS   
select
  t_merce_ass.id_merce,
  t_merce_ass.id_posizione,
  t_merce_ass.prezzo,
  t_tipo_merci.nome
from
  t_merce_ass,
  t_tipo_merci
where
  t_tipo_merci.id_merce = t_merce_ass.id_merce
```

And this is the instead of trigger:

```
create or replace trigger TG_UPDATE_VM_TEST
instead of update on VM_TEST
for each row
begin   
  update
    t_tipo_merci
  set
    t_tipo_merci.nome = :NEW.nome
  where
    t_tipo_merci.id_merce = :OLD.id_merce;
  update
    t_merce_ass
  set
    t_merce_ass.prezzo = :NEW.prezzo
  where
    t_merce_ass.id_merce = :OLD.id_merce
    and
    t_merce_ass.id_posizione = :OLD.id_posizione;
end TG_UPDATE_VM_TEST;
```

Update now is working fine, via sqlplus but it's not working with the grid, because it executes an update with returning clause (logged with Oracle Monitor):

```
00:31.996   00:00.001   Query.Execute update VM_TEST  set PREZZO = :v3  where rowid = :doa__rowid  returning rowid into :doa__rowid
```

and it rise a **ORA-22816** exception (`Unsupported feature with RETURNING clause`).

How to fix the problem? Is there a way to return rowid in this type of trigger to make the grid's update command work?

Comment: you're returning rowid from a view?

Comment: What database components do you use?

Comment: We are using TOracleDataSet. I suppose that the component request the rowid after the update to locate the modified record in the internal table.

Comment: @tbone, I'm not, but the Component need it and I'm looking a way to use TcxGrid's edit components and a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Direct Oracle Access forum](http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=postlist&Board=1&page=1) (search for ORA-22816), you probably have to set the UniqueFields property.

Comment: can you post solution here

Comment: @user482963 You just have to set the UniqueFields property of the TOracleDataSet (as I wrote in my answer).